# Parenting objects to Bézier control point handles?

Tags: bezier-curves

I can parent objects to Bézier control points easily enough. However, when I try to do the same with the control point handles, the objects still parent to the main control point. Is it possible to somehow parent objects to control point handles, whether natively or via plugin?

Comment: You can add a hook, by selecting the control point and ctrl-h ('new object') it will add an empty.  That empty is now the parent of the control point, and you can further parent objects to the empty.

Comment: My goal is to be able to move objects around by manipulating the handles, whereas this approach would force me to move the hook object.